# Kubernetes Pod giving my access denied when trying to write file to cifs mount

Tags: kubernetes, cifs

I'm working on a project that requires writing data to a cifs storage. I am using fstab/cifs flex volume. https://github.com/fstab/cifs

When I run the following yaml I get the error

> sh: 1: cannot create /app/xxx/test.txt : Permission denied

I have confirmed the mount is mounting by doing an ls of the directory and it shows everything on the cifs storage. So why can't a create a file?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
   name: test
   namespace: xxx
spec:
   securityContext:
      fsGroup: 2000
   containers:
   - name: test
     image: "docker-repo.XXX.test:5000/xxx/test:latest"
     command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo test > /app/xxx/test.txt']
     securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1001
        runAsGroup: 2000
     volumeMounts:
     - name: exsnap
       mountPath: /app/xxx
   volumes:
   - name: exsnap
     flexVolume:
        driver: "fstab/cifs"
        fsType: "cifs"
        secretRef:
           name: "xxx-secret"
        options:
           networkPath: "//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/DATA/"
           mountOptions: "vers=2.0,dir_mode=0766,file_mode=0666,noperm"
```

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate more on the error that you are getting when trying to create a file? Is it a permission denied or some other error? Have you checked the permissions on this volume?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't fully type out the error. I am getting permission denied. I have ran list -l on the directory and files inside and they all mimic whatever the mount options are. So once I get the first denie I opened everything up so dirs have 766 and files have 666.

Comment: Please try to change the dir permission to `777` as per this: [Execute vs read bit how do directory permissions in linux work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work) and let me know if it helped.